# Python tkinter nested function in separate window

Tags: python, tkinter

Using tkinter, I am trying to make a numerical methods calculator. I have a starting window(root) where there's a drop down menu that gives the user 3 options. When they choose an option it opens a new window where the user is asked for the inputs, and the method will be solved, and answer displayed. I haven't written the numerical methods part yet, but the problem I'm running into is the clear button for my interpolation window. I want to make a clear button that clears the input boxes in that window, but it isn't showing up.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.title("Numerical Methods Calculator")

welcomeMessage = Label(root, text="Welcome! Are you ready to solve some numerical methods?")
welcomeMessage.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=20, columnspan=3)

def linear():
    top = Toplevel()
    top.title('Solve Linear Equation')
    x1 = Entry(top)
    x1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=20)

def polynomial():
    third = Toplevel()
    third.title('Solve Polynomial Roots')

def interpolation():
    second = Toplevel()
    second.title('Solve Interpolation')
    instructions = Label(second, text="Please fill in five values, and leave one blank. Then click the solve button, and the last value will be solved.")
    instructions.grid(row=0,column=0, pady=20, columnspan=3)

    def buttonClear():
        x1.delete(0, END)
        x2.delete(0, END)
        x3.delete(0, END)
        y1.delete(0, END)
        y2.delete(0, END)
        y3.delete(0, END)

    def solveButton():
        return

    xLabel = Label(second, text="x")
    xLabel.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3)

    x1 = Entry(second)
    x1.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=3, pady=1)
    x2 = Entry(second)
    x2.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=3, pady=1)
    x3 = Entry(second)
    x3.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=3, pady=1)

    yLabel = Label(second, text="y")
    yLabel.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=3)

    y1 = Entry(second)
    y1.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=3, pady=1)
    y2 = Entry(second)
    y2.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=3, pady=1)
    y3 = Entry(second)
    y3.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=3, pady=1)

    myButton = Button(second, text="Solve", command=solveButton, fg="black")
    myButton.grid(row=5, column=0, pady=5, columnspan=3)

    clearButton = Button(second, text="Clear", fg="black")
    clearButton.grid(row=6, column=0, pady=5, command=buttonClear, columnspan=3)

menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)
equationMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="Choose Numerical Method", menu=equationMenu)
equationMenu.add_command(label="Solve Linear Equations", command=linear)
equationMenu.add_command(label="Solve Interpolation", command=interpolation)
equationMenu.add_command(label="Solve Polynomial Roots", command=polynomial)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the `command=buttonClear` in `Button(...)` instead, not in `grid(...)`:

```py
    clearButton = Button(second, text="Clear", fg="black", command=buttonClear)
    clearButton.grid(row=6, column=0, pady=5, columnspan=3)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That was the issue. Sometimes it's the little things lol

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code might help :

```
from tkinter import *

def buttonClear():
    x1.delete(0, END)
    x2.delete(0, END)
    x3.delete(0, END)
    y1.delete(0, END)
    y2.delete(0, END)
    y3.delete(0, END)

def solveButton():
    pass

second = Tk()
second.title('Solve Interpolation')
instructions = Label(second, text="Please fill in five values, and leave one blank. Then click the solve button, and the last value will be solved.")
instructions.grid(row=0,column=0, pady=20, columnspan=3)
    
xLabel = Label(second, text="x")
xLabel.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3)

x1 = Entry(second)
x1.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=3, pady=1)
x2 = Entry(second)
x2.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=3, pady=1)
x3 = Entry(second)
x3.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=3, pady=1)

yLabel = Label(second, text="y")
yLabel.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=3)

y1 = Entry(second)
y1.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=3, pady=1)
y2 = Entry(second)
y2.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=3, pady=1)
y3 = Entry(second)
y3.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=3, pady=1)

myButton = Button(second, text="Solve", command=solveButton, fg="black")
myButton.grid(row=5, column=0, pady=5, columnspan=3)

clearButton = Button(second, text="Clear", fg="black",command=buttonClear) # command should be with Button not grid
clearButton.grid(row=6, column=0, pady=5, columnspan=3)
second.mainloop()
```